# Count how many times a node is referenced

Tags: views

I have a content type: **classroom**

I have another content type: **lesson**

Lesson nodes have an entity reference field (field_classroom) that reference classrooms.

I want to create a view that outputs a table like this:

| Classroom | Number of lessons |
| --- | --- |
| Leicester Square | 5 |
| Piccadilly Circus | 8 |
| London Bridge | 0 |

So, there are five lesson nodes that reference the "Leicester Square" classroom (all the classrooms are named after places in London), 8 that reference the classroom named Piccadilly Circus, and 0 lesson nodes referencing London Bridge.

Is there a way to achieve this in views?

I'm playing around with relationships and aggregation but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly mistake. I had the relationship the wrong way round. Now it's working perfectly. These are the steps:

1.) Create a relationship: *Content **using** field_classroom* (not *content referenced from field_classroom*)

2.) Enable aggregation

3.) Add a field: field_classroom

4.) Use the relationship

5.) Set aggregation on the field to COUNT

And it works!